# Ropsten Ethereum not showing transaction information

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ropsten

I am using `geth 1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d` to sync with `Ropsten` network. I started synchronization with `fast` mode and restarted the service. When I type `eth.syncing` in geth console it always shows `false` but the new blocks are being imported.

`eth.blockNumber` in my node returns **4374961** but when I try to get one of the transaction info from that block then it returns `null`.

When will the transaction info of the blocks be downloaded in my node? I already removed the test database 3 times and started fresh with `fast` sync mode. I have 11 peers right now in my node. Do I need to change something to download block info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ropsten has [forked](https://twitter.com/peter_szilagyi/status/1047873843023548417) at block 4320000.

> Via community decision, we've delayed the #Ethereum Ropsten testnet Constantinople hard fork by 1 epoch to block #4230000 (+5 days) to allow clients to implement, test and release an update to CREATE2, countering a recently found EVM DoS attack vector.

You have to update to at least [geth v1.8.17](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.8.17)

> Geth v1.8.17 is our regular maintenance release, which among numerous bugfixes also features the full Constantinople feature set and enables it on the Ropsten testnet at block #4230000.

Comment: Thanks, I updated and started syncing with `Ropsten (revival)` bootnodes and everything is updated as expected.